# Can I Install Liferay 6.1 EE in clustered Glassfish 2.1.1?

Tags: cluster-computing, liferay-6, glassfish-2.x

I have a simple question about installation Liferay **6.1** EE into clustered environment in Glassfish **2.1.1** web application server, the question is can I do that , if yes what I need of configuration if not why , whats the problem ?

I have already a stable production server clustered and running Liferay 5.2 EE with Glassfish 2.1.1 and I want just upgrade Liferay with current clustered environment .

I want the answer quickly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I made a PoC , and seems working, I installed Liferay 6.1 CE on glassfish 2.1.1 (with JDK 7 32-bit) as a standalone and clustered and seems working.

About performance and stability, I didn't make any test, but just a run and startup for portal yes working well without exceptions, I tried that on Glassfish 2.1.1 installed on windows with JDK 1.7 (32-bit), but for 64-bit failed in cluster mode because a bug in Glassfish 2.1.1 side with 64-bit Windows OS (known as ClassNotFoundException sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11), but as a standalone working well in 64-bit too.